# Sql query combine 2 or more columns into one cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

my query brings 3 fields
For example, if I have the following code:

---

```
select C.ContactId,C.CityId,C.ZipCode
from Contacts C
Where c.ContactId=256
```

---

all fields are int type

but I want all in one cell
I thought it might be like the statement below;but it didnt work

---

```
select Convert(varchar(50),C.ContactId+','C.CityId,C.ZipCode)
From Contacts C
```

Comment: Use right tool for the job. Formating result of the query is "business" layer job. So you can do it in your `.net` code which handle result of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of lad2025 is elegant.
But you can do this too:

```
   select cast(C.ContactId as varchar(50)) + ',' + cast(C.CityIdas varchar(50)) + ',' + cast(C.ZipCode as varchar(50))
   from Contacts C
   Where c.ContactId=256
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`FORMATMESSAGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788.aspx):

```
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('%i %i %i', C.ContactId, C.CityId, C.ZipCode)
FROM Contacts C
WHERE C.ContactId = 256;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/RCIU47321)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Concat has more support

```
SELECT CONCAT ( 'Happy ', 'Birthday ', 11, '/', '25' ) AS Result;
```

Here is the result set.

Happy Birthday 11/25

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Comment: @lad2025 Microsoft wrote it, better appearance maybe